# Datadog logging within Gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, datadog

Hey I am trying to logging within a script and send a log message to Datadog via their api: POST https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com/v1/input. My issue is that the code works perfectly well when running on the team's machine but once it's in the pipeline, it keeps throwing 400 errors as a response from Datadog. The Key is perfectly valid and the log message works on our machine so I cannot see why I am getting a 400 error. Wondering if anyone else has run into this problem

[pic of gitlab-cl.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FrmQ.png)

Thanks,

soln: make sure your api key in gitlab can be accessed on all branches

Comment: Can you provide your (redacted) `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Comment: Sure @AdamMarshall it's now in the org post